# Adaptive cards on SKYPE

Tags: azure, bots, chatbot, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

I came to know adaptive cards doesnt support Skype at this point of time. Is there any update on the same? Is there any alternative for Adaptive cards?. Basically i am looking for Card which gets me Input Text / Form where i capture login information

NOTE: I donot want to use Signin card

Answer (score 1):

No Skype still doesn't support for Adaptive cards,

Use the below link to verify.

[Channel Inspector](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/Skype?f=AdaptiveCards&e=example1)